# How to read a line from stdin with max input length?

Tags: rust

To read a line from `Stdin`, I could

```rust
let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();
let mut input = String::new();
stdin.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
```

To read from `Stdin` with a maximum length, I could do

```rust
const MAX_LENGTH: u64 = 256;
let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();
let mut input = String::new();
stdin.take(MAX_LENGTH).read(&mut input).unwrap();
```

What I want is the combination of the above two requires. Read a line from stdin, and if the input is longer than `MAX_LENGTH`, the remaining is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_line` is not a member of `std::io::Read` but of `std::io::BufRead`, and while `stdin` does implement the latter, the return of `stdin.take()` (of type `std::io::Take<_>`) does not.

But you can convert any `Read` into a `BufRead` easily using `std::io::BufReader`:

```
const MAX_LENGTH: u64 = 256;
let mut stdin = std::io::stdin();
let mut input = String::new();
let mut bstdin = std::io::BufReader::new(stdin.take(MAX_LENGTH));
bstdin.read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
```

Comment: The documentation on `std::io::Tale` suggests that it takes N _bytes_ from the input stream. This means that if your input is not single byte UTF8 characters you wont actually get a string of MAX_LENGTH, but something shorter. You may also hit an error if take ends up splitting a multi-byte character?